# Times New Roman in LaTeX just some text

Tags: fonts

I have some text in my document in primary font what is in LaTeX but I would like to get some text in font Times New Roman but just some text between primary text, as a local command (something as `\textit{}`, `\textbf{}` etc.), an example below.

> My cat has black skin. % in primary font
>
> My second cat has white skin. % I would like to get in Times New Roman

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can choose pretty much any font you want at pretty much any time using the features of package `fontspec`.

Comment: Can you write me some examples. I don't understand. :)

Comment: I cannot, i have to leave no. Have a look at the package documentation or search the site for `fontspec`.

Comment: But I use pdftex. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Option 1: LaTeX

Select the Times font, which looks a lot like Times New Roman. More info [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document).

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
My cat has black skin. % in primary font

{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
My second cat has white skin.} % I would like to get in Times New Roman
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

## Option 2: XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX

Select fonts installed on you computer using `fontspec` as Johannes_B suggested. Now you have to compile using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX though. (thanks clemens)

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% Compile with XeLaTeX

\newfontfamily\myfont{times.ttf}
\begin{document}
My cat has black skin. % in primary font

{\myfont
My second cat has white skin.} % I would like to get in Times New Roman
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: *Now you have to compile using XeLaTeX though.* misses a “or LuaLaTeX” :)

Comment: @clemens thanks. Never used it. Added it to the answer.