# Fonts in LaTeX and their commands

Tags: fonts

Good evening.

I would like to use the same fonts what are in MS Word in LaTeX. But I want to use them just as a command - I do not want to use them in all document. I mean something like shortcuts \textit, textbf, etc.. Fonts what I want to use in LaTeX: Arial, Times New Romans etc.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Package `fontspec` and a unicode engine like XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: Can you write me so examples, please? I need just one or two examples. Thank you.

Comment: See pages 8 and 9 of the [fontspec manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf).

Comment: Can you give us an example we can modify to show you rather than asking people to start from scratch? But, really, the `fontspec` manual already includes examples and there are lots more on this site. So there really isn't any need for examples in response here as there's nothing new here.

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331108/times-new-roman-in-latex-just-some-text?rq=1, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33739/how-to-use-the-ms-trebuchet-font?rq=1 (non-unicode engine answer) etc. Those are just from the list of 'related' questions in the panel on the right.